# Conversion of void* in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c

In C, a `void` pointer is implicitly typecasted to another type.

See below program:

```
int main()
{
    void *p;
    int* ptr,i=5;
    p=&i;
    ptr=p; <---------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

The program [compiles successfully](http://ideone.com/ZEW8d) when run under C environment.

However, if the same program is run under C++ environment, i am getting the below [error](http://ideone.com/4WHUr):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’
```

It means that in C++, we need to explicitly typecase a `void` pointer.

So, Why the return type of the `new` operator is void*? How, it is being converted to the desired type?

Comment: I think you can instruct the C compiler to be more pedantic regarding implicit casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you overload `operator new`, you indeed return a `void*`. An overloaded `operator new` is basically a simple allocation function like `malloc()` in C.

But when you *use* operator `new`, you are doing more than just calling that function; you also implicitly call the constructor for example. Returning the exact correct type is another implicit difference between constructing with `new`, and your overloaded `operator new` function.

C++ gives you an error because `void*` could point to *anything*. So if you try to assign it to something specific, you are making an assumption that may not be true. As C++ is strongly-typed, you must tell the compiler about your assumption and be explicit about it; that's the protection mechanism that type safety provides. C is not strongly typed and it's solely the responsibility of the developer to take care.

Comment: +1 Yes - Quite agree. Should add C++ is strongly typed. C is not.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator is treated specially by the compiler, it get the type from the argument to `new` and does an implicit cast to the correct type.

If you create your own `operator new` you have to return a `void` pointer, since you actually doesn't know the type, just the amount of memory you need to allocate.

Answer (score 1):

Because `new` is not a function, it is an operator and is handled specially by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

C++ imposes more strict rules to pointer cast. One of the reasons is probably because pointer cast in C++ eventually may lead to a machine code, i.e. it's not a purely cosmetic thing.

For example class `A` inherits `B` and `C` (in this order). If you take a pointer to `C` and cast it to `A` - this result to a (raw) pointer shift.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter:

```
  ptr = (int *) p;
```

The result of new is not a void *. It depends on the object you are creating.
If you do

```
  ptr = new int [2];
```

there's no recasting involved.

Comment: Here a reinterpret_cast<int*>(p) is preferred to a C-style cast. C++ provides different cast operators, they should be used.

Comment: Avoid `reinterpret_cast` -- in this case `static_cast` is not only sufficient, but also preferable/recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> So, Why the return type of the new operator is void*?

Do you mean the keyword `new`, used in a new-expression like `int * p = new int[42];`? That expression has the correct type, in this case `int*`, so no conversion is necessary.

Or do you mean the memory allocation function `operator new()`? Like `malloc()`, that is dealing with raw memory, not typed objects, and so its return type is an untyped `void*`. It's used internally by a new-expression, which knows the type of the object being created and so can perform the necessary pointer conversion once the objects have been fully constructed.

On the very rare occasions when you want to use it in your own code, you'll have to convert it to the correct type yourself; but you'd nearly always use it indirectly through a new-expression, and not have to worry about such details.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/

> operator new can be called explicitly as a regular function, but in
>   C++, new is an operator with a very specific behavior: An expression
>   with the new operator, first calls function operator new with the size
>   of its type specifier as first argument, and if this is successful, it
>   then automatically initializes or constructs the object (if needed).
>   Finally, the expression evaluates as a pointer to the appropriate
>   type.

Note the final sentence.